# Best LINQ way to create dictionary from list of custom entities

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of DeleteByVendor objects.. It has two business entities – vendor and pricepage ..  One pricepage can have multiple vendors.. And one vendor can be present in multiple pricepages.

We need to create a dictionary that will have each pricepage and the number of (`distinct`) vendors present in that pricepage.  One pricepage should be present only once in that dictionary.

How can we do it using `LINQ chain method` approach?

Note: For "P3" the count should be 1 (though there is a duplicate record)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<DeleteByVendor> vendorsForPages = new List<DeleteByVendor>();

        DeleteByVendor item1 = new DeleteByVendor() { VendorID = "V1", VendorName = "Vendor1", PricePage = "P1", Description = "Description1" };
        DeleteByVendor item2 = new DeleteByVendor() { VendorID = "V2", VendorName = "Vendor2", PricePage = "P1", Description = "Description1" };
        DeleteByVendor item3 = new DeleteByVendor() { VendorID = "V1", VendorName = "Vendor1", PricePage = "P2", Description = "Description2" };
        DeleteByVendor item4 = new DeleteByVendor() { VendorID = "V1", VendorName = "Vendor1", PricePage = "P3", Description = "Description3" };
        //Duplicate
        DeleteByVendor item5 = new DeleteByVendor() { VendorID = "V1", VendorName = "Vendor1", PricePage = "P3", Description = "Description3" };

        Dictionary<string, int> costPageVendorsCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    }
}

public class DeleteByVendor
{
    public string VendorID { get; set; }
    public string VendorName { get; set; }
    public string PricePage { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group your list by `PricePage` first using `GroupBy` method. Then use `ToDictionary` to get a dictionary.

```
var results = vendorsForPages.GroupBy(v => v.PricePage)
                             .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                                           g => g.Select(x => x.VendorID)
                                                 .Distinct()
                                                 .Count());
```

Comment: But it is not taking the unique vendor count.. For "P3" it is showing as count 2. It should be 1

Answer (score 2):

You can group by `PricePage` then by `VendorId`:

```
var costPageVendorsCount = vendorsForPages.GroupBy(v => v.PricePage)
                                          .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, 
                                                        g => g.GroupBy(gg => gg.VendorID)
                                                              .Count()
                                                       );
```